# Controlling formatting when importing data into excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

At my company, we use an electronic visitor sign-in/out system via an app titled Envoy. The data from the application can be exported to Excel from the admin interface on the host-site by clicking a download link, but carries a lot of unnecessary information with it that is ultimately taken out.

Can I create a default format for that specific set of data when importing it?

If not, what alternatives can I look into?

Comment: People would need more info to help you.  What program is it coming from, what is the export process, what extra info is coming in.  Can you bring it into an excel template (Maybe have a raw data sheet and a sheet that formats/takes the data you want).

Comment: @gtwebb I have improved my question using your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into Power Query, a free add-in from Microsoft for Excel 2010 and Excel 2013, and built into Excel 2016 as "Get and Transform" in the Data ribbon.

Let Envoy export the data to Excel or CSV format, then create a query into that file. In the query you can transform, shape, tidy up the data and load it to a worksheet for further processing. The query can be refreshed when the data source changes (for example when you export form Envoy the next time and save with the same file name). Power Query is very powerful and can do lots of things with data from different sources.

Comment: I have been playing with Power Query, and it has worked wonderfully. Thank you for the suggestion!